# How to redirect to external url using filters when controller does not exist in current app

Tags: grails, redirect

I have the following filter that in app1 that is supposed to redirect to an external app (app2).

```
class MyFilters {
    def userService
    def springSecurityService

    def filters = {
        all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                String userAgent = request.getHeader('User-Agent')

                int buildVersion = 0

                // Match "app-/{version}" where {version} is the build number
                def matcher = userAgent =~ "(?i)app(?:-\\w+)?\\/(\\d+)"

                if (matcher.getCount() > 0)
                {                   
                    buildVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcher[0][1])

                    log.info("User agent is from a mobile with build version = " + buildVersion)
                    log.info("User agent = " + userAgent)

                    String redirectUrl = "https://anotherdomain.com"

                    if (buildVersion > 12)
                    {
                        if (request.queryString != null)
                        {
                            log.info("Redirecting request to anotherdomain with query string")
                            redirect(url:"${redirectUrl}${request.forwardURI}?${request.queryString}",params:params)
                        }

                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
            after = { model ->
                if (model) {
                    model['currentUser'] = userService.currentUser
                }
            }
            afterView = {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

A problem occurs when the request to app1 contains a URI where the controller name does not exist in app1 (But does in app2 where I want to redirect to).

How can I redirect requests to app2 with same URI appended? (regardless if they exist in app1 or not).

I suspect filter's are not the correct solution as it will never enter them if the controller does not exist in app.

Ideally, I need a solution that can be implmented via code and not apache.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set the scope of a filter](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6.1%20Applying%20Filters) by URI as well as by controller name, try:

```
def filters = {
    all(uri:'/**') {
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a general purpose redirect controller like this:

```
class RedirectController {

def index() {
        redirect(url: "https://anotherdomain.com")
    }
}
```

In UrlMappings, point 404 to this controller:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        ......
        "404"(controller:'redirect', action:'index')
            ......
    }
}
```

Actually you can define all the redirect relationships here instead of deal with filter.

Comment: nice idea. though genuine 404s will also get redirected (not that that is a big problem)

Comment: If that is a problem, just define the mappings as usual.

Comment: That was a nice suggestion. Even with much-improved interceptors in Grails 3, this can still be utilized. :)